# 3D modeling in WPF using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, maya

Is it possible to open the 3d maya file in wpf application and do transformations in wpf application itself, if so how to do it,,, can recomend some samples?

Answer (score 3):

This is a tool to convert maya files to XAML:
http://www.creativecrash.com/maya/downloads/applications/3d-converters/c/maya-to-xaml

Taken from a similar question on the mdsn forums:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/2826/7705.aspx